# Fetch multiple records for same object

Tags: childrecords

I have been doing a lot of research and haven't found an answer that suits my needs yet and would greatly appreciate any input. I am interested in creating an email template (most likely visualforce and custom controller) that can fetch multiple reservation records for a single account object.

Specifically-
For each account (custom object called Viper in this scenario), I want to be able to access each reservation listed under their account and display them individually. For example:

1. For Account(Viper)

   - Reservation #1 object details

     - all desired fields from this reservation
   - Reservation #2 object details

     - all desired fields from this reservation

Is it possible to structure the Viper custom object as an equivalent to Contact, Lead, or User? I am trying to use the Viper as the top level of the directory and then from there access its related objects.

I've included a screenshot of the way I'd like to reference it below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All information can be found here:

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_soql_sosl.pdf

Basically you need a Parent-to-child query. The following will get all contact related to the account

```
[Select id, name, (Select LastName From Contacts) From Account Where Id = {yourid}];
```

The Parent-to-child query will pull the values from the Relationship between the Contact and the Account. On custom Objects this will be the *child relationship name* on the field definition followed by `__r`

```
[Select Id, (Select Id From ChilcRelationshipName__r) From ParentObject__c];
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_results.htm?search_text=subquery

Comment: can I do this within an html email template or use a controller and then have it embedded? or do I need to use visual force to use SOQL

Comment: @JimWeglin - You can use it anywhere you can use SOQL. If you add a controller to your template then you can use it.

Comment: Hi Eric,
Thanks for everything thus far. Is there any way I may create a visualforce template with Viper as the recipient type vs Contact, Lead, or User? Viper is not associated with any of those entities in our schema and I'm curious if that may cause issues going forward

Comment: @JimWeglin - Yes you can. You set the recipient in the email alert. If you are using apex the how depends on your implementation. There are ways around every roadblock.

Comment: Awesome, thanks Eric. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my questions. Do you have any suggestions for how to do this within the visual force template? My screenshot below is where I'm at, and the html embedded within renders properly in a normal custom template but I just can't get past these emailTemplate errors 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/mh6b31jnqzyokiu/Screenshot%202017-04-12%2017.47.46.png?dl=0

Comment: @JimWeglin - Suggest you start a new question as I think this is taking a different direction that how to query. Or maybe I misunderstood but the tag was childrecords. I would suggest you also visit [Ask] so you can get answers targeted more to your actual question.